EnDAT encoder resolution issues
I am working with an old motor with EnDAT encoder, no documents are available. The protocol is implemented on FPGA and can be changed, as needed.
Somehow the encoder sends 13 bits. Other servo drive seems to get 21 bits, which also makes more sense.
The problem - i don't know which encoder is that and don't have a datasheet.
So i hope someone here has an idea about how to get more resolution out of it.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

That's the question. I don't have it more specific. There is more resolution and I don't know how to get it. I hope that someone in the community either saw it or has an Idea.
